# Developing an ad with MRAID.js

Tags: javascript, mraid

I need to develop an ad that's MRAID compliant. I'll be hand-coding the ad in HTML5 and not using any authoring software with an MRAID SDK. According to the spec, mraid.js gets injected by the SDK where the ad is hosted. How do I get access to the MRAID functions to test when developing the ad? As far as I can tell there is no centralized library of functions for MRAID (like there is for jQuery), and its left up to the SDK developers to build these functions? Am I misunderstanding MRAID entirely? I have reviewed the spec and while it defines the properties of these functions, I'm still not really understanding how the initial mraid.js file would be compiled

-Matt-

Answer (score 1):

You can test MRAID ads using the MRAID Test Page here: http://webtester.mraid.org/

It's good for basic testing of your ad. You may want to do some testing on actual devices which you can do on mopub.com.

Comment: Kesty, what are some of the reasons an mraid compatible ad tag will work on the mraid.org site, but fail inside an app environment? I think inside the app, it simply isn't seeing the mraid ready event...

Comment: I've experienced that. The best way to debug that is to use an emulator and put debugger statements into your code to find the place where it's crashing. Hope this helps.